# css Possible to generate the Content itself with Generated Content (:after/:before)

Tags: css

html

```
<h1>My Headline</h1>
```

css

```
h1:after {
   content: ?content?;
}
```

Is it possible to display the content of h1 a second time with generated Content?

So that the result will be:

`My HeadlineMy Headline`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer: NO

Unfortunately, there's no *content* selector in CSS. So the answer is no.

However, you could use an attribute for the `<h1>` element and use [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) CSS expression to do the trick:

```html
<h1 title="This is a heading">This is a heading</h1>
```

```css
h1:after {
  content: " " attr(title);
}
```

It's worth noting that `attr()` [is supported in **IE8+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_Compatibility).

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gisuj/1/edit)**.

Alternatively, you could use HTML5 **[data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)** to achieve the same result *(As [@MrAlien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542290/mr-alien) suggested)* which [is supported in **IE8+**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) as well:

```html
<h1 data-title="This is a heading">This is a heading</h1>
```

```css
h1:after {
  content: " " attr(data-title);
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gisuj/2/edit)**.

Comment: that's not so nice. but it there is defenitly NO WAY to get the content itself?

Comment: hasheem, I would better suggest you to use a custom attribute rather than using `title` http://jsfiddle.net/59t5m/

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith I'm afraid that there's no *content* selector in CSS. So the answer is no. Alternatively you could use HTML5 [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to achieve that.

Comment: @HashemQolami Can you please update your answer with a big fat "NO"! thx ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could use JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function ( ) {

    $('h1').each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + $(this).text());
    });
});
```